# gulpとbabelを使用したトランスパイルができません

Tags: gulp

gulp-uglifyはes6に対応していないので、gulpでタスクを組むときに、gulp-babelを使用してトランスパイルをするようにしているのですが、エラーを見る限りトランスパイルがうまくいっていません。

エラーメッセージ、gulpfile、対象のコードを載せています。
色々な可能性を提示していただけるととても助かります。

エラーメッセージ

```
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: keyword «const»
File: ~path/dist/some.js
Line: 37497
```

gulpfile.js

```js
const gulp       = require("gulp"),
    uglify     = require("gulp-uglify"),
    rename  = require('gulp-rename'),
    config  = require('../config'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('build-javascript', () => {
    return gulp
        .src([
            'assets/javascript/hoge.js',
        ])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename(path => {
            extname: 'some.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

assets/javascript/hoge.js

```js
const hoge = "hoge";
```

ちなみに、 `npx gulp build-javascript`を実行した時の結果は以下のようになっています。(babelがうまく動いていないのでしょうか)

```
Using gulpfile ~path/gulpfile.js
Starting 'build-javascript'...
'build-javascript' errored after 639 ms
GulpUglifyError in plugin "gulp-babel"
Message:
    unable to minify JavaScript
```

Comment: ちなみに、新しいディレクトリに同様の手順でやるとトランスパイルできているので、それがまた謎です。

Comment: 自己解決いたしました。
多くのサイトで `gulp-uglify` でできていて、自分で適当にディレクトリ切って試してみたときにもうまくいっていたのですが、

`gulp-uglify-es` をインストールして、requireすることで解決しました。
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify-es